# Storing data in a 2d matrix with interchangeable x/y coordinates

Tags: c++, arrays

I have a list of nodes in C++, and I wish to store the distance between each pair of nodes in some kind of data structure `dist`

For example, 5 nodes: (0, 1, 2, 3, 4)

I want to store the distance between each of them.
I could store them in a 2d matrix, but then I am storing redundant data.

`dist[1][3]`, which stores the distance between node 1 and 3, would hold the same value as `dist[3][1]`

Furthermore `dist[0][0]`, `dist[1][1]`, `dist[2][2]`, .. are not needed and also waste data.

I considered a 1d array with a mapping function that maps [x][y] coordinates to an array index, but it could become hard to read and understand when revisiting the code.

What is a good way to store some values between arbitrarily-ordered indices like this in C++?

Comment: It's ok using 1d array with a encode/decode index function

Comment: "a 1d array with a mapping function that maps [x][y] coordinates to an array index". Nothing wrong with that idea. The mapping is not that complicated. Add a comment explaining the math if you worry about maintainability.

Comment: What kind of allocation?

Comment: In theory with the number of nodes I am using I could use the wasteful 2d matrix method. However, now I am just curious and wanted some answers purely for learning purposes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The right abstraction is a `class`, which wraps data access for you.

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <array>

template <typename TNumber, std::size_t Dimension>
class triangular_matrix
{
public:
    // It's common/friendly to make a value_type for containers
    using value_type = TNumber;

    // Overloading operator() is fairly common and looks pretty decent
    value_type operator()(std::size_t row, std::size_t col) const
    {
        return _data.at(index_of(row, col));
    }

    // A non-const overload allows users to edit using regular assignment (=)
    value_type& operator()(std::size_t row, std::size_t col)
    {
        return _data.at(index_of(row, col));
    }

private:
    // You're storing 1 less than the dimensions
    static constexpr stored_dim = Dimension - 1;

    // Use sum of arithmetic series:
    static constexpr data_size = stored_dim / 2U;

    static std::size_t index_of(std::size_t row, std::size_t col)
    {
        // I'm not sure what you want to do for this case -- you said these
        // indexes aren't needed, but I don't know if you mean they won't be
        // accessed or what...so just throw!
        if (row == col)
            throw std::invalid_argument("row and column can't be the same!");

        // flip
        if (row > col)
            std::swap(row, col);

        // This is probably not the fastest way to do this...
        --row;
        std::size_t index = 0U;
        for (; row > 0U; --row)
            index += row;
        return index + col;
    }

    // Store using a flat array
    std::array<TNumber, data_size> _data;
};
```

Usage looks like this:

```
triangular_matrix<double, 4> m;
m(1, 3) = 5.2;
m(2, 1) = 9.1;
assert(m(2, 1) == m(1, 2));
```

Comment: Thank you, very insightful and I actually am inspired to properly learn templates in C++ now which I never got around to doing before.